# Does the immediate window provide a nice way to display a primitive array?

Tags: visual-studio, arrays, c++-cli, immediate-window

I dynamically assigned an array as follows:

`unsigned char **nonces=new unsigned char*[n_cases]`

Is there a way to nicely print it out in the immediate window? Alternatively, it would be nice to make the locals window display it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard problem with C arrays, not even the debugger can know how long they are.  You have to tell it that with a watch expression like nonces[0],12.  You tagged this with C++/CLI, it is not a problem with managed arrays:

```
array<array<unsigned char>^>^ nonces = gcnew array<array<unsigned char>^>(n_cases);
nonces[0] = gcnew array<unsigned char>(42);
// etc..
```

Comment: So there is a nice way for the locals window, but not for the immediate window or does the expression work in both?

Comment: It works in both the immediate window and the watch. Other format specifiers are available too: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75w45ekt%28VS.80%29.aspx